# Decrypting with GPG after a "su - different user"

Tags: permissions, terminal, su, gpg, pinentry

I have cron job running a script in the cron of "USER A" that encrypts many files in a loop using the gpg command below:

`gpg --batch --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase "PASSWORDISHERE"  -c FILENAME`

"USER A" has elevated permissions, can not be SSH'ed to, and is only logged in by normal users when needed. So, when I SSH in as myself (Bob), I can decrypt the encrypted files. However, when I "su -" over to USER A and try to decrypt I get the error below:

```
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
can't connect to `/home/USERA/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file or directory
gpg-agent[27859]: command get_passphrase failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I have done a bunch of research and found many things relating to tty and pinentry. The only solution I found was to use `chmod o+rw $(tty)`, but this is not a good long term solution for me not to mention I don't want to use this method anyway. Does anybody have any better ideas?

Comment: Note that unless you have a very recent kernel and the right setting (whose name I forget), the passphrase will be visible by all users while the `gpg` command is running, simply by running `ps`. To avoid this, use some other method of passing the passphrase, such as `--passphrase-file` (which will otherwise be just as secure, since the passphrase is stored in the crontab file anyway — and in fact more secure since the passphrase won't be exposed to shoulder surfing while you edit the crontab).